# How to enter text in TinyMCE editor with Selenium IDE in firefox 14

Tags: tinymce, selenium-ide

I made a test which is working in newer or older firefox versions, slower or faster internet connection (at least I say that internet of my virtual machine in vmware is slow), but something and I don't know what causes a failure after typeKeys command in another computer. Somehow text is not written in the TinyMCE editor and therefore assertion fails.

Can anyone tell me what could cause such a thing or maybe there are incompatible commands?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://tinymce.com" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>http://tinymce.com/tryit</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
    <td>15000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=demo_tab</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=content_ifr</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectFrame</td>
    <td>id=content_ifr</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>focus</td>
    <td>//body[@id='tinymce']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>//body[@id='tinymce']</td>
    <td>(1,1)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>typeKeys</td>
    <td>//body[@id='tinymce']</td>
    <td>writing something in this silly form</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>fireEvent</td>
    <td>//body[@id='tinymce']</td>
    <td>blur</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertTextPresent</td>
    <td>writing something</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectFrame</td>
    <td>relative=parent</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=submitbtn</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>id=submitbtn</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForTextPresent</td>
    <td>Post dump</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertTextPresent</td>
    <td>HTML output from post</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyTextPresent</td>
    <td>writing something</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Don't hesitate to ask if I wasn't clear enough.

Thanks for replies in advance.

Comment: I just found out that my test doesn't work specifically with firefox 14.0.1. And also the line "typeKeys" becomes grey - didn't find what does it mean. Any solutions for this browser?

Answer (score 3):

Try using 
Command | runScript 
Target | tinyMCE.get('text_area_id_not_iframe_id').setContent('Your text') 
Which will work on specific tinyMCE's or if you have multiple tinyMCEs on one page 
Otherwise if you only have one tinyMCE, runScript | tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('Your text')

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's working for me, essentially, by selecting the frame (others have suggested this), then the click and focus commands will make it the active editor, allowing the sendKeys command to work.  In this example, I'm passing a variable to the editor as well as saving the iframe TinyMCE creates as a variable.  For instances where multiple, I'm looping through them based on the ${frame} variable. 
<

```
tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectFrame</td>
    <td>xpath=//*[contains (@id, '${frame}')]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=//*[contains (@id, 'tinymce')]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>focus</td>
    <td>xpath=//*[contains (@id, 'tinymce')]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>sendKeys</td>
    <td>xpath=//*[contains (@id, 'tinymce')]</td>
    <td>${date} ${frame}</td>
</tr>
```